# How to resolve Undefined Table error in Django

Tags: django

I am new to django , was following a tutorial on youtube, on how to create custom user model.

This is my model

```
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser , BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email,firstName,lastName,m_phone):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email Id is a required Field')
        if not firstName:
            raise ValueError('First name is a required Field')
        if not lastName:
            raise ValueError('Last name is a required Field')
        if not m_phone:
            raise ValueError('Mobile Ph. no  is a required Field')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                          firstName=firstName,
                          lastName = lastName,
                          m_phone  = m_phone)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email,firstName,lastName,m_phone,password):
        
        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                          firstName=firstName,
                          lastName = lastName,
                          m_phone  = m_phone,
                          password = password)

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user






class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    firstname            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname             = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    m_phone              = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    l_phone              = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_joined          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active            = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff             = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstname','lastname','m_phone']

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):

        return self.firstName

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



# class Profile(models.Model):

#   user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
#   profilePicture = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pictures')


#   def __str__(self):
#       return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

While running createsuperuser command, after entering email address I get the below error message

```
"Email: test@gmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users_account" does not exist
LINE 1: ...unt"."is_active", "users_account"."is_staff" FROM "users_acc...

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 113, in handle
    error_msg = self._validate_username(username, verbose_field_name, database)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 234, in _validate_username
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 44, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\591705\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_account" does not exist
LINE 1: ...unt"."is_active", "users_account"."is_staff" FROM "users_acc...
```

No where I have mentioend a table called "users_account" , as shown in the error message. Can anyboady point out where I went wrong ? Any help is much appreciated

0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.3 on 2020-09-21 05:40

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Account',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)),
                ('firstname', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('lastname', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('m_phone', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('l_phone', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('is_admin', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: did you create & run migrations for your user model? Have you set [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) in settings appropriately?

Comment: yes I ran python manage.py makemigrations and then ran migrate command. Also from my setting.py AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Account'

Comment: Please check migrations folder if the migrations actually run

Comment: I have added contents of 0001.py file as well.